# Asus Xtion live pro on USB 3.0 - ROS-kinetic - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
to connect my asus xtion pro live.

But i have errors : Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data.

What may cause this problem?

I use ROS kinetic, Ubuntu16.04, my asus xtion live pro supports openni2 not openni. It seems the answers here are mostly about previous versions of softwares. Anyone encounter such problems in latest versions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249504/asus-xtion-live-pro-on-usb-3.0---ros-kinetic---ubuntu-16.04/) by [fredli](https://answers.ros.org/users/28727/fredli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is only a warning. Your Xtion should still work.

> OpenNI tries to set the USB async
> thread priority to critical. This
> works on Linux only with root
> privileges. For a normal user, the
> program will throw this warning. To
> get rid of this warning, run the
> program as root. [source](https://codeyarns.com/2015/08/05/openni-usb-thread-priority-warning/)

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fredli](https://answers.ros.org/users/28727/fredli/) on 2016-12-09**:
Oh Thx. Yes it works indeed haha